# Could Gentle Repose work for the purposes of Breath of life?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Say you had a wizard under the effect of [Contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency) so that if he died [gentle repose](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gentle-repose) was cast on him. Would a cleric with [breath of life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/breath-of-life) be able to come over at any time even after more than that one round had passed but not after gentle repose had ended?

Gentle Repose

> You preserve the remains of a dead creature so that they do not decay. Doing so effectively extends the time limit on raising that creature from the dead (see raise dead).

Breath of life

> Unlike other spells that heal damage, breath of life can bring recently slain creatures back to life. If cast upon a creature that has died within 1 round, apply the healing from this spell to the creature.

Yes I know that breath of life has a specific condition of 1 round. But gentle repose also has a specific condition in which it extends the time in which a creature can be raised from the dead (which does also mention raise dead). But in this case would breath of life work on the dead character?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/does-gentle-repose-extend-the-time-limit-for-casting-revivify

Answer (score 3):

Based on how death and souls work in Pathfinder and in D&D, I would say that preserving your body isn't enough to allow *breath of life* to successfully revive you : after the one round delay before *breath of life* is cast, your soul leaves your body and only a *raise dead* spell can bring it back.

Comment: Breath of Life does not mention any requirement on soul presence so unless there is something that can be quoted here that states that souls leave after exactly 1 round, and can then be linked to Breath of Life I don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: I think the soul might stay as long as the writers of a spell *need* it to stay; take the spell [*soul bind*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/soul-bind), for example.