# Spell to have the living count as the dead for other spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Does anyone know of a core pathfinder spell which causes a living creature to count as dead for the purposes of other spells which only target the dead?

My goal is to have gentle repose in effect on a living creature, so that in the case of death, resurrecting them with breath of life is an easy process which doesnt need to be done within a single round.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a spell, or is that an unnecessary restriction we can trim from the question? Also, do you want to use spells that target the *dead* or the *undead* (or both)?

Comment: You could try "Slay Living", although it has some side-effects.

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the question. I have updated it and removed the incorrect description.

Comment: Can we conclude from the edit that the method does *not* have to be a spell? (If so, an edit to the title and first paragraph to remove that restriction is probably in order.)

Comment: The fact gentle repose can make you able to resurrect someone with breath of life later on is already quite uncertain. You even [already asked for that](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88253/could-gentle-repose-work-for-the-purposes-of-breath-of-life).

Comment: A cleric spell would be most convenient  as long as its not too high of a level. What other methods were you thinking of because I want to be able to do this to the party.

Comment: Please just answer the question. The post asks for spells. Does it have to be a spell? If yes: explaining why it needs to be a spell would help us understand the scope of the problem (e.g., your last comment implies there may be a specific PC restriction we need to know about). If no, we can remove that and let the *answers* decide how to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

While I do not know of any spells that lets a living creature be affected as if dead/undead, the premise of your question can be answered by another spell. Namely [Contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency)

From the description:

> You can place another spell upon your person so that it comes into effect under some condition you dictate when casting contingency.

Should fit your needs quite nicely, as it fulfills the "in case of" requirement. :)